# Typescript generics: types 'T' and 'number' have no overlap error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this example:

```
function foo<T>(t: T): boolean {
  return t === 1;
}
```

I get `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T' and 'number' have no overlap.`.

The error goes away if I change it to:

```
function foo<T extends any>(t: T): boolean {
  return t === 1;
}
```

I thought `T` could be `any` by default, so why did I need `extends any`? Without `extends any`, what type does TS expect `T` to be?

Edit, actual function:

```
function cleanObj<T>(
  obj: ObjectOf<T>,
): ObjectOf<T> {
  const newObj = {};
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[k] !== null && typeof obj[k] !== 'undefined' && obj[k] !== false) {
      newObj[k] = obj[k];
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say its `any` by default, it's behaviour is more like `unknown` which for your case, would also fail because you can't compare to a type that you're not aware of. As @MoxxiManagarm said, if you don't need the generics, just get rid of them.

Comment: I do need the generic, but there's no need to paste a long function when 3 lines suffice to explain the problem

Comment: At compile time the type of `T` would be known, isn't that the whole point of generics? Even if it's unknown, the error "always return 'false'" is still wrong, since `unknown` doesn't mean it can't be a number

Comment: @MikeS. except `<T extends unknown>` works fine, the same as `extends any`

Comment: @MingweiSamuel oops, my bad, yes you can compare to `unknown`, you just can't assign anything to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially taken from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17445 :

Consider your original function:

```
function compare<T>(obj: T): boolean {
  return obj === 1;
}
```

if it would be allowed to compare anything to `T` we could also write:

```
function compare<T>(obj: T): boolean {
  return obj === 'some-string-thats-definitely-not-obj';
}
```

If you use that function inside of some `if`, you could potentially create unreachable code that won't throw an error.

This is why typescript requires you to explicitely tell it that `T` can be `any`, which is obviously unsafe for the above reason.

Comment: Wouldn't a more reasonable solution to be to treat `<T>` as an implicit any? I.e. it'll cause an error with `noImplicitAny` on, but by default it's the same as `<T extends any>`

Comment: No, `T` shouldn't be able to be compared to like `any` or `unknown`. In the case of generics extending `any`, it wouldn't be worse to just set the parameter to `any` itself.

Comment: As for a solution, I think the recommended thing to do is to just upcast `1` to `{}` or `unknown`, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

The triple equals operator `===` returns true if both operands are of the same type **and** contain the same value. Compared to that `"1" == 1` would return true.

Since you use `===` you also compare the type, which is `number` for the right hand operant `1`. However, your T can not just be a number, that is why the compiler gives you this notification.

*Possible solutions:*

- remove the generics if not really necessary
- use `==` instead of `===`
- (possible further approaches depending on your actual code)

Comment: This doesn't explain why explicitly doing `T extends any` fixes it, since `number` != `any`.

Comment: @LeoJiang No, but `any` can very well be a `number`

Comment: I still don't get the answer at all. I'll paste my full function. My question is basically what's the difference between `<T>` and `<T extends any>`, I thought they should be the same thing